# swift - Initializing another class inside a class?

Tags: class, swift, object

Hello everybody I am a beginner in programing FYI! This is the problem that I have: I have two classes: Human and Pet. The Pet class has a method called eat that prints a simple "eat" line. The Human class has a method that calls the eat method from the Pet class. The way I am trying to implement this is by creating a Pet object inside the Human class so that a Human method can call the Pet methods.

Is this a right way to go about this? I'm also running into problems attempting to create the Pet inside Human...

This is what I have so far:

```
class Human{
var humanName: String
var Pet = Pets(petName: String, noise: String, canMakeNoise: Bool)

init(humanName: String, petName: String, noise: String, canMakeNoise: Bool){
    self.humanName = humanName

func feedPet(){
        //insert Feed function here
    }

class Pets{
var petName: String
var noise: String
var canMakeNoise: Bool

init(petName: String, noise:String, canMakeNoise:Bool){
    self.petName = petName
    self.noise = noise
    self.canMakeNoise = canMakeNoise
}

func eat(){
    println("\(self.petName) is eating...")
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line:

```
var pet = Pets(petName: String, noise: String, canMakeNoise: Bool)
```

to this line:

```
var pet: Pets?
```

And after that you can create an instance of your Human class such as:

```
var human = Human(humanName: "chris", petName: "abc", noise: "hi", canMakeNoise: true)
var dog = Pets(petName: "erty", noise:"bark", canMakeNoise:true)
human.pet = dog
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did var pet = pets? but now its complaining, "Expected member name or constructor call after type name"

Comment: Sorry i have edited my answer. You should use `var pet: Pets?`

Comment: it worked! thank you so much, been stuck here forever!

Comment: @MichaelNinh As it helped, please mark ridvankucuk's answer as correct (click the tick).